# Using doxygen macros with autoconf

Tags: c++, build-automation, doxygen, autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to use doxygen to document my project's source code, and I'm using autotools for the build system. I've downloaded the `ax_prog_doxygen.m4` macro from the autoconf-archive repository, made the changes to aminclude.am and made sure to call DX_INIT_DOXYGEN and the rest in configure.ac.

All commands to generate the configure scripts and makefiles work correctly, but I can't actually make the project anymore, failing with this error:

```
Makefile:833: *** missing separator.  Stop
```

Full code is at https://gist.github.com/3690227

Comment: I ended up ditching autoconf for my project and going with CMake, which luckily supports doxygen also.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when you copy/download macros from a different OS. Check the format of the files (**unix/windows**) and also use a consistent indentation policy (either **tabs or spaces**), especially on the Makefiles.

Good luck!

Comment: I just checked, all are Unix line endings, with space indentation.

Comment: But! In makefiles, sometimes tabs are required. In a list of commands after a rule, each one must be indented with a tab.